# Not able to open an app using Process() in swift returns Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

I have created two cocoa applications for macOS and I am trying to open one application from another on a button click but this returns an error `Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"` I even removed the app sandboxing in both the applications but still the same error, Any help would be appreciated.

**Development Environment:**

```
OSX: 10.14.5 (Mojave)
Xcode: 11.2.1
Swift: 4.2
```

**Code Sample:**

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let task = Process.init()
        task.launchPath = "/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/ExampleApp.app"
        task.arguments = ["--args", "hello"]
        do{
            try task.run()
        }
        catch{
            print("Error: ", error)
        }

        task.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of the shell the application bundle is a folder, you have to launch the executable

```
/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/ExampleApp.app/Contents/MacOS/ExampleApp
```

Disabling the sandbox is required to run something with `Process`

Comment: Hi, that worked like a charm when done from a cocoa application but when I try to open the process from a bundle project which is a [authorization plugin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/authorization_plug-ins/using_authorization_plug-ins) which runs during log in it gives me `XPC API Misuse: Attempt to look up cross UID boundaries by unprivileged process.` I have posted this issue in here if you want to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60812043/not-able-to-open-a-process-in-authorization-plugin-in-swift

Comment: I wasted nearly a whole day b/c I kept calling `MyApp.app` instead of `MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`. Thanks to your answer it didn't cost me 2 days.